# Room lights flickering when I connect my laptop through inverter

Tags: electrical, wiring, light, inverter

I am using amaron 880v inverter with 1500mah Tall tubular battery when I connect my laptop 130w charger then room lights are flickering then I checked with another laptop 90w charger then same lights flickering is happening if I connect my 130w laptop and 90w laptop with out inverter then lights are not flickering

I buyed last month only new inverter I am facing from the first day then I contact customer care then they sended technician but no use he said I can't find the issue so other technician will approach me

What I need to do now and what issue I was facing with inverter

How to solve the issue

Comment: Where are you on this planet even?  Are these lights LED perchance?

Comment: are the room lights somehow connected to the inverter?

Comment: How much does the battery weigh/weight?

Comment: Yes lights are connected to inverter

Comment: Some are led and non led lights